# Why use client/server design when making program for local network?

Tags: qt, client-server

I've never done any network programming before, so excuse me if this as dumb. I'm planning on using Qt to make a fairly simple program that tracks changes on up to ten drives, on computers that are on a local network, and copies changes to a central computer. I'm wondering why I can't just treat those locations as being local and keep the program simpler than it otherwise would be if i used client/server architecture? I'm making the assumption that a program could see the drives in the same way that I can see them in the windows GUI, maybe thats a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about "network drives", then it should work, since windows does all the network stuff (it's a protocol called SMB, that allows access to those drives as if they where local).

You will need the path, off course, but if you can access the drive using the explorer, I guess you know it. (Something line `\\OTHER_PC\sharedFolder\myFile.txt`)

If you want to make shure, just try to open the file with `QFile` (or watch for changes using `QFileSystemWatcher`). I'm pretty shure that it will work.

Regarding whether you should or not:
Thats basically your desicion. As long as you don't want to support other operating systems or drives, that are not available as "network drive", you don't have to use sockets. It's easier and propably more efficient that way. If you want to extend it later, you may safe some work if you do it via sockets right now.

Comment: Thanks. The drives can be selected manually at the start of the operation and the program will be closed at the end, each time its used, so I think this approach makes sense. It's to monitor shots being captured on an array.